# Disable the spelling correction on ML Digital Ink Recognition

Tags: python, ios, google-mlkit

can someone please help me disable the spelling correction when using Googles ML Digital Ink Recognition. I need the recogniser to skip this step.

Thanks so much

I can't find the disable function in the code. The advise I got was to disable spelling correction in Google's ML digital ink recognition by can using the ⁠ setLanguageModel ⁠ method with the ⁠ enableSpellCorrection ⁠ parameter set to false. But I cannot find this function.

Thanks so much